# pgrep and pkill alternatives on mac os x?

Tags: osx, grep, kill

Are there alternatives to `pgrep` and `pkill` commands on Mac OS X or should I just create aliases for them using other commands available for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/): `sudo port install proctools`

Here's the result of `port search pgrep`:

```
proctools @0.4pre1 (sysutils)
    pgrep, pkill and pfind for OpenBSD and Darwin (Mac OS X)
```

Comment: proctools is also available via [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall is right. For homebrew try `brew install proctools`

Answer (score 19):

On OS X Lion with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install proctools
```

This downloads, builds and installs `pgrep`, `pkill` and `pfind`.

Comment: Would there be possible to build a GUI to work in the way xkill does but for OSX

Answer (score 16):

You don't need an alternative anymore: since MacOS 10.8 `pgrep` and `pkill` are available by default.

Comment: Unfortunately as of 10.15.7, there is a nasty bug where pgrep and pkill when typically  used with the `-f` option (match against the full argument list) silently truncate process lists to 2048 characters. Below the actual process list limit ARG_MAX 256 kB in syslimits.h (or from `getconf ARG_MAX`).

`ps` won't truncate the list so you might be better off relying on that or proctools if you need to match on long process lists (such as java commands that have long classpath arguments).

Comment: @tmoschou You can find the source for Apple's pkill on [opensource.apple.com/source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-176.100.1/pkill/pkill.c.auto.html). It's together with other utilities in the collection _adv_cmds_. Maybe you can spot the bug.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that you are using some relatively recent version of Bash in the Mac, you could write your own version of `pgrep` as function and then add that to your `.bashrc` file:

```
function pgrep() {
    ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep
}
```

as for `pkill` you can use the following:

```
function pkill() {
    local pid
    pid=$(ps ax | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
    kill -9 $pid
    echo -n "Killed $1 (process $pid)"
}
```

Comment: I'm on a Z Shell, although there should be no problems in adapting this.

Comment: or /bin/kill $(ps ax | awk '$5 ~ /'"$1"'/ { print $1 }') 
for a more faithful pgrep (process name only, not args. I use /bin/kill out of habit because it reliably takes more than one PID to kill. There are other tricks, if you're in control of the regexp to never have to 'grep -v grep' - that way you can pkill greps!)

Comment: I suggest you remove the `function` keyword, it's deprecated. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654700/what-are-the-parentheses-used-for-in-a-bash-shell-script-function/4654730#4654730)

Comment: You are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

[Proctools](http://proctools.sourceforge.net/) includes `pgrep` and `pkill` and is available for OpenBSD and OSX. It hasn't been updated in a while, but it should still work (at least on OSX which rarely modifies its ABI).

Comment: Proctools doesn't compile well with Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1):

you could try killall.
It kills processes by name. Any processes that match the string you pass in are killed.

```
killall httpd ( kill all apache processes )
killall php ( kill all php process )
```

If you do

```
killall -s man ( kill any manual page processes, if a user is using man [command]
```

it will show you a list of processes that would be killed like below.

```
kill -TERM 70836
```

If you want a different signal do the following

```
killall -9 processname
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution for pkill:

```
#!/bin/sh

for X in `ps acx | grep -i $1 | awk {'print $1'}`; do
    kill -9 $X;
done
```