# Bash script to find and kill a process with certain arguments?

Tags: bash, process

I want a script which kills the instance(s) of `ssh` which are run with the -D argument (setting up a local proxy).

Manually, I do `ps -A | grep -i ssh`, look for the instance(s) with -D, and `kill -9 {id}` each one.

But what does that look like in bash script form?

(I am on Mac OS X but will install any necessary commands via `port`)

Comment: See [pgrep and pkill alternatives on mac os x?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225/pgrep-and-pkill-alternatives-on-mac-os-x). `pgrep` and `pkill` are commands to reliably find or kill processes by name under Solaris and Linux.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run `pgrep -f "ssh.*-D"` and see if that returns the correct process ID.  If it does, simply change `pgrep` to `pkill` and keep the same options and pattern

Also, you shouldn't use `kill -9` aka SIGKILL unless absolutely necessary because programs can't trap SIGKILL to clean up after themselves before they exit.  I only use `kill -9` after first trying `-1` `-2` and `-3`.

Comment: you should redefine kill as a `for` loop that does `kill -i` for each `i` ;)

Comment: `pgrep` is not native on OSX, you have to get it from a third party. [The previous thread on the topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225/pgrep-and-pkill-alternatives-on-mac-os-x) has proposals and alternatives.

Comment: man alive, the more I use 'nix, the more I love it :) thanks for this!

Comment: pgrep and pkill are available in OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and above.

http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/interesting-new-unix-commandsbinaries-in-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: It might be useful to add the `-a` flag to `pgrep` which makes it print not only the process id but also the command (including arguments). This way it is very easy to verify that only desired processes are matched.

Answer (score 2):

Also,

```
kill `pgrep -f "ssh.*-D"`
```

Comment: I think this is equivalent to `pkill`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the proc file system to gather the information. For example:

```
for proc in $(grep -irl "ssh.*-D" /proc/*/cmdline | grep -v "self"); do if [ -f $proc ]; then cat $proc && echo ""; fi; done
```

It's not perfect, you'll want a more exclusive regex (especially if you are killing processes) but `echo $proc | awk -F'/' '{ print $3 }'` will show you the PID of the process(es).

Comment: OSX doesn't have `/proc`. And there's already a robust tool to do this out there, called `pgrep` (available natively at least on Solaris and Linux).