# How do I know if dd is still working?

Tags: osx, hard-disk, dd, file-transfer

I've not used `dd` all that much, but so far it's not failed me yet. Right now, I've had a `dd` going for over 12 hours - I'm writing an image back to the disk it came from - and I'm getting a little worried, as I was able to `dd` from the disk to the image in about 7 hours.

I'm running OSX 10.6.6 on a MacBook with a Core 2 Duo at 2.1ghz/core with 4gb RAM. I'm reading from a .dmg on a 7200rpm hard drive (the boot drive), and I'm writing to a 7200rpm drive connected over a SATA-to-USB connector. I left the blocksize at default, and the image is about 160gb.

EDIT: And, after 14 hours of pure stress, the `dd` worked perfectly after all. Next time, though, I'm going to run it through `pv` and track it with `strace`. Thanks to everyone for all your help.

Comment: Not answering your question, but your times are quite high IMO. Did you remember to pass a bigger block size to dd other than the default 512 bytes? `dd ... bs=16M` is my suggestion, given your RAM, disk size and speed.

Comment: I didn't, simply because I wanted to play it safe. I'll try that next time, though. Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, `dd` on Mac OS X has a tendency to freeze to the point where I can't even kill the process, but have to restart the system. I resort to doing work on a Linux VM then.

Comment: as pointed by @Juliano, a higher `bs` does make a huge difference in speed, by orders of magnitude

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can send [`dd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dd.1.html) a certain signal using the `kill` command to make it output its current status. The signal is `INFO` on BSD systems (including OSX) and `USR1` on Linux. In your case:

```
kill -INFO $PID
```

You can find the process id (`$PID` above) with the `ps` command; or see [pgrep and pkill alternatives on mac os x](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225/pgrep-and-pkill-alternatives-on-mac-os-x) for more convenient methods.

More simply, as [AntoineG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22308/antoineg) points out in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59076/977), you can type `ctrl-T` at the shell running dd to send it the `INFO` signal.

As an example on Linux, you could make all active `dd` processes output status like this:

```
pkill -USR1 -x dd
```

After outputting its status, `dd` will continue coping.

Comment: Oh, very cool. You can combine those with `pkill -USR1 -x dd`

Comment: Checked the `man` page for `kill`, and there's no mention of `-USR1` - what does that do? I'm really nervous about running any form of `kill` on this process, as I have a client waiting on this to finish.

Comment: Start another `dd` doing something easy and try it on that before you risk breaking your big one. I don't know what USR1 stands for but my guess is it's a custom (user 1?) signal that different process might handle differently.

Comment: No, it definitely stopped the process and spit out "User defined signal 1". Good thing I tried it on something extraneous. :P

Comment: My Ubuntu box says to use `$ kill -s INFO $pid; wait $pid`.  "On systems lacking the 'INFO' signal 'dd' responds to the 'USR1' signal instead, unless the 'POSIXLY_CORRECT' environment variable is set."

Comment: @kivetros: On BSD systems, you need to send the `INFO` signal. Linux doesn't have a SIGINFO and uses `USR1` instead.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for tracking down the different signal on BSD.

Comment: The SIGUSRx signals are for programs to do what they want with, as opposed to having a standardized meaning.  SIGWINCH, for example, is raised when the terminal has changed its size and the program might need to redraw its screen.  The operating system doesn't send SIGUSRx's so they are available for custom uses.

Comment: Sending dd the USR1 signal _too soon_ after it has started (i.e. in a bash script, the line after you started it) will in fact terminate it. Put a 0.1 second sleep in between and it will output its progress properly. By the way, a very nice dd command to test USR1/INFO on is `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null`. :)

Comment: BTW, all "true" BSDs send SIGINFO to foreground process group if status character (Ctrl+T by default) is sent to terminal. But I don't know whether is it true for MacOSX.

Comment: I can confirm that OSX also sends SIGINFO when using ctrl-t. Great tip!

Comment: `CTRL+T` does it pretty well.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek `pkill -USR1 -x dd` actually killed the dd process.

Comment: @DanLoewenherz Possibly you [ran it too soon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38589/73) after starting `dd`? It should be functionally the same as using `kill`, it just saves the step of looking up the PID

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Odd...nope, ran it about 5 mins after starting. Weird, maybe it was just a fluke?

Comment: @Dan it does work if you have the right signal for the right platfom. Play with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` and see what you can get sending different signals.

Comment: `kill -USR1` on OSX just seems to kill the `dd` process, lamentably.

Comment: When I used the command `pkill -USR1 -x dd` my `dd` process stopped, i did not get a progress status, and I had to restart it. Why would this have happened?

Comment: @ob1 Sounds like you used the wrong signal for your platform.

Answer (score 114):

Under OS X (didn't try on Linux), you can simply type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in the terminal running `dd`.  It will print the same output as `kill -INFO $PID`, plus the CPU usage:

```
load: 1.40  cmd: dd 34536 uninterruptible 3.49u 64.58s
5020305+0 records in
5020304+0 records out
2570395648 bytes transferred in 4284.349974 secs (599950 bytes/sec)
```

I found out about it reading this thread, and trying to open a new tab in my terminal but mixing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: Oh, OK, so `load` is the CPU usage?

Comment: this was so much a better solution!

Comment: I tried in dd on Linux, it just echoes `^T` to the terminal.

Comment: make sure you are doing ctrl+shift+T in mac terminal

Comment: from reading in other forums, it is possible to combine those commands with grep, so to ask grep to read the PID of dd for you:
sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd$)

Comment: I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 and the trick with CTRL+T works flawlessly!

Answer (score 27):

For `dd`, you can [send a signal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/dd-how-do-i-know-if-its-still-working/11264#11264). For other commands that are reading or writing to a file, you can watch their position in the file with [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).

```
lsof -o -p1234    # where 1234 is the process ID of the command
lsof -o /path/to/file
```

If you plan in advance, pipe the data through [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

Comment: pv looks amazing - I'm definitely going to use that next time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 17):

A more general way is to use [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) that displays the current amount of
disk reading / writing per program.

EDIT: `iotop -o` show only programs which perform currently I/O operations (thanks [Jason C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49422/jason-c) for this comment).

Comment: This is my preferred quick check method as well. `iotop -o` will hide processes that are not doing IO and make it easier to tell at a glance what's going on.

Answer (score 17):

As of `coreutils` v8.24, `dd` has native support for showing progress. Just add the option `status=progress`.

Example:

```
dd if=arch.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress
```

[Source](https://reddit.com/r/linux/comments/40c2km/did_you_know_about_dds_builtin_progress/)

Comment: best answer for linux. I tried with ubuntu and it works.  In Mac Ctrl+T

Answer (score 13):

I usually attach `strace` to such a running process (with the `-p $PID` option) to see if it stays blocked in a system call or if it is still active.

Or, if you feel nervous about sending a signal to the running dd, start another dd to validate if this works.

Comment: How exactly would you go about attaching `strace`? Also, I did start another `dd` and send one of the suggested signals to it, and... it killed it.

Comment: If you know the pid of the running dd process, just do strace -p <pid>. You should see the log of all system calls called by the process (mostly read and write)

Answer (score 11):

For next time, you can just use `pv` from the start (if it's available through your package manager, install it). This is a utility with the sole purpose of piping input to output and monitoring progress and speed.

Then, for writing an image to a drive, say with 4MB block size:

```
pv -ptearb /path/to/image.bin | dd iflag=fullblock of=/dev/whatever bs=4M
```

Aside from initial buffering (offset by a final sync, which can be done through `dd` if you want), this will show you a progress bar, average speed, current speed, and ETA.

The `iflag=fullblock` option forces dd to grab full blocks of input through `pv`, otherwise you're at the mercy of the pipe for block sizes.

To go the other way use dd to read and pv to write, although you have to explicitly specify the size if the source is a block device. For a 4GB device:

```
dd if=/dev/whatever bs=4M | pv -ptearb -s 4096m > /path/to/image.bin
```

You could also determine the size automatically, something like:

```
dd if=/dev/whatever bs=4M | pv -ptearb -s `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/whatever` > /path/to/image.bin
```

It really doesn't matter what order you do `dd` and `pv` in, it's entirely performance-related -- if the device you are reading to or from has optimal performance for certain blocksizes you want to use `dd` instead of `pv` to access that device. You can even stick a `dd` on both ends if you want, or not at all if you don't care:

```
pv -ptearb /path/to/image.bin > /dev/whatever
sync
```

Answer (score 5):

`ddrescue` will give you stats as it's running.

demo:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqq9A01geeA#t=144s

Comment: This might be helpful for the next time, but it won't help the OP to understand if the current command is frozen or not.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you may not be able to use the INFO or USR1 signal because the stderr stream of the `dd` process is not accessible (e.g. because the terminal in which it was executed was already closed). In this case, a workaround is to do the following (tested on FreeBSD, may be slightly different on Linux):

1. Use `iostat` to estimate the average write rate (MB/s) to the target device, e.g.:

   `iostat -d -w30 ada0`

   Substitute your target device name for `ada0` here, and wait a minute for it to give a couple results. The "w" parameter determines how many seconds between samples. Increasing it will give a better average estimate with less variance, but you'll have to wait longer.
2. Use `ps` to determine how long `dd` has been running:

   `ps -xo etime,command | grep dd`

   Convert this to seconds to get total seconds of runtime.
3. Multiply total seconds of runtime by average write rate to get total transferred MB.
4. Get the device size in MB with:

   `grep ada0 /var/run/dmesg.boot`

   Substitute your target device name for `ada0`. Divide the result by the average write rate to get the total transfer time in seconds. Subtract the time it's been running so far to get time remaining.

This strategy only works if `dd` has been writing continuously at the current average write rate since it began. If other processes are competing for the CPU or I/O resources (including the I/O bus) then it may reduce the transfer rate.

Answer (score 4):

I started using dcfldd(1), which shows dd operations in a better way.

Answer (score 3):

While `dd` is executing, run this in another terminal as root:

```
while pgrep ^dd; do pkill -INFO dd; sleep 1; done
```

It prints the `dd` status every 1 second **in the original terminal window** where `dd` is executing, and quits when the command is done.

Comment: So cool. Worked fine here under El Capitan

Comment: zsh: parse error near `do'

Comment: I've used this in macOS Ventura with success:

`sudo sh -c 'while pgrep ^dd; do pkill -INFO dd; sleep 1; done'`

Comment: @Mansueli: the command was tested to work fine with both `bash` and `zsh` (both with and without loading custom profiles)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) which, in particular, shows the progress of a running `dd`. It uses `/proc/$pid/fd` and `/proc/$pid/fdinfo`  which you can also monitor by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The `wchar` line (written characters) in `/proc/$pid/io` can give you precise information about the `dd` process. As long as it changes, your `dd` is still working!

Here is a neat little php script, which you can save and then execute with `php filename.php` during the `dd` to display the written bytes. The nice benefit of watching `/proc/$pid/io` over `kill -USR1 $(pidof dd)` is that you do not have to switch between terminals, which is not always an option.

```
<?php

/** Time between refreshs in seconds */
$refresh = 1;


/**
 * Start of Script 
 */

if (!($pid = exec('pidof dd')))
    exit("no dd running\n");

$history = array();
$break_ms = $refresh * 1000000;
$start_time = exec("ls -ld /proc/$pid --time-style=+\"%s\" | egrep -o [0-9]{10}");


fprintf(STDOUT, "PID: %s\n", $pid);
fprintf(STDOUT, "START TIME: %s\n\n", date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_time));


while (true) {
    if (isset($curr))
        array_push($history, $curr);

    if (count($history) > 10) array_shift($history);
    $oldest = reset($history);
    $latest = end($history);

    /**
     * get number of written bytes from /proc/$pid/io
     */
    #if (!($curr = exec("cat /proc/$pid/io | grep ^write_bytes | sed 's/write_bytes: //g'")))
    #    break;

    /* prepare proc_open() parameter */
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
        2 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stderr
    );

    $process = proc_open("cat /proc/$pid/io | grep ^write_bytes | sed 's/write_bytes: //g'", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    if (!is_resource($process)) break;

    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);

    if (!empty($stderr)) break;
    $curr = trim($stdout);

    /**
     * caculate elapsed time from start */
    $time_elapsed = time() - $start_time;

    /**
     * avg speed since start */
    $avg = $time_elapsed > 0 ? round($curr / $time_elapsed) : 0;

    /**
     * avg speed of last 10 updates */
    if (count($history) > 0)
        $speed = human_file_size(round(($latest - $oldest) / count($history) / $refresh));

    $output = sprintf("\rBYTES WRITTEN: %s [%s]  ::  CURRENT: %s/s  ::  AVERAGE: %s/s  ::  ELAPSED: %s", $curr, human_file_size($curr), isset($speed) ? $speed : 0, human_file_size($avg), gmdate("H:i:s", $time_elapsed));
    printf("%s%s", $output, str_repeat(" ", exec("tput cols") - strlen($output)));

    usleep($break_ms);
}

fprintf(STDOUT, "\ndd has finished!\n\n");

function human_file_size($size,$unit="") {
  if( (!$unit && $size >= 1<<30) || $unit == "GB")
    return number_format($size/(1<<30),2)." GB";
  if( (!$unit && $size >= 1<<20) || $unit == "MB")
    return number_format($size/(1<<20),2)." MB";
  if( (!$unit && $size >= 1<<10) || $unit == "kB")
    return number_format($size/(1<<10),2)." kB";
  return number_format($size)." bytes";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write to a slow drive, for example a USB drive, you may want to know not only the progress of the command `dd` itself, but also the progress of actual writing to the target device.

- One way way know when the process has finished is to run `sync` after the dd command and wait for it to finish flushing the buffers, so that the terminal window returns to prompt. But there is still no display of progress. You can monitor the progress of flushing by watching the 'dirty' data for example with the shellscript `watch-flush`, that is part of [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). This shell-script uses data from the system file `/proc/meminfo`.
- It is more straightforward to modify the `dd` command line to make it flush the buffers regularly, for example after writing each mibibyte, and at the same time show the progress, for example

  ```
  sudo dd if=file.img bs=1M of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=dsync
  ```

  Please check and double-check, that you specify the correct target device. Otherwise you might overwrite valuable data. `dd` does what you tell it to do without any questions, and for this reason it has earned the nickname 'Data Destroyer'.
- In Ubuntu and Debian you can also use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to perform the cloning task. It will wrap a safety belt around `dd`: help you identify the target device and let you double-check it before you launch the process.