# How to check progress when cloning a disk using `dd`?

Tags: dd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dd: How do I know if it's still working?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/dd-how-do-i-know-if-its-still-working)

I'm using `dd` to clone a disk to an image file, and compress it on the fly:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip > /mnt/image_file
```

How can I check how much data `dd` already processed?
Looking at the output file size is of course useless, due to it being compressed.

Comment: If you haven't yet started `dd` and want to monitor its progress, check out *[How to monitor the progress of dd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/215505/39012)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most `dd` implementations print status information upon recieving `SIGUSR1`. `pkill -USR1 -x dd` is probably what you want.

Comment: b-e-a-utilful. The only thing I can add is: while true; do pkill -USR1 -x dd; sleep 1; done

Comment: @Fidel If you truly want beautiful, you should let it end when `dd` isn't around any more: `while pkill -USR1 -x dd; do sleep 1; done` ;-)

Comment: Not all implementations of dd respond this way to SIGUSR1 (my Mac's implementation requires SIGINFO) so it's worth checking in the man page.

Comment: Be wary and test this on your system before using it - on FreeBSD sending SIGUSR1 to `dd` will terminate it (FreeBSD uses SIGINFO, so substitute "INFO" for "USR1").

Answer (score 5):

Try [`pv`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pipeviewer/), the pipe viewer.  I just tested and it works on `/dev/sda` directly, meaning you even get a deterministic progress bar.

---

Regarding the times:

I created a random file with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random bs=4k count=10000`. I then tried several methods of reading it:

```
$ time dd if=random | gzip >rand.gz
800000+0 records in
800000+0 records out
409600000 bytes (410 MB) copied, 17.9261 s, 22.8 MB/s

real    0m17.940s
user    0m16.545s
sys     0m1.248s
$ time pv random | gzip >rand.gz
 391MB 0:00:17 [22.1MB/s] [==================================>] 100%            

real    0m18.048s
user    0m16.477s
sys     0m1.048s
$ time <random gzip >rand.gz

real    0m18.410s
user    0m16.401s
sys     0m0.596s
```

I ran it again, `pv` and `dd` were even closer and lower than `<`.  I conclude that the performance of `pv` and `dd` are the same to within a very small margin of error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not available on the live CD I'm using to do the cloning (and besides, I'm halfway through and I'd rather *not* stop it only to change the command line). Nice to know, though.

Comment: It will (marginally) slow down the transfer, however.

Comment: @ChrisDown Perhaps a small amount, I don't think it'll be the bottleneck.

Comment: That would depend on the hardware in use. I could imagine it happening on an SSD with an old-ish machine.

Comment: @ChrisDown I was thinking of `gzip` as the bottleneck, which would almost certainly be the case on an older machine.

Comment: Ah yes, I was talking in a generic fashion.