# How to use / send signals at the command-line, for any program (eg. dd)

Tags: shell, background-process, signals

I trying to understand the manpage of the `dd` program, which mentions:

> Sending a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O statistics to standard error and then resume copying.
>
> ```
>          $ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null& pid=$!
>          $ kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 1; kill $pid
> ```

What does `pid=$!` mean?

Is this an assignment of a variable, which gets the pid of `dd`?
And is eventually used in the `$pid` variable?

Also why do they use `sleep` and `kill`?

Is this the way to use `-USR1`?

Comment: not an answer to understanding dd, but have you seen pv? for example: dd if=/dev/zero | pv | dd of=/dev/null, it also supports a progress bar...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null&`

The trailing `&` means run the prefix command in background. (Disclaimer: This is oversimplified statement)

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1074998):

> $! is the PID of the most recent background command.

So `pid=$!` assign the **most Recent background PID** to variable pid, which is `dd` PID.

> Also why they use sleep and kill?.

You need `kill $pid` **(if not specified parameter, default  signal  for kill is TERM which is process termination)** to terminate the `dd` process after you done testing, otherwise `dd` process may just stay in background and exhausting your CPU resources. Check your System Monitor of your platform to see.

Whereas `Kill -USR1 $pid` print I/O statistics, it doesn't terminate the process.

Without sleep 1 second, your `dd` process may get terminated by last command statement `kill $pid`** before have the chance to write statistics output to your terminal. The processes is synchronous but **trap+write operation** (`kill -USR1 $pid`) may slower than **terminate operation** (`kill $pid`). So `sleep 1` second to delay the startup of `kill $pid` to ensure statistics output done printing.

> This is the way to use -USR1?

Just `man dd`:

> Sending a USR1 signal to a running 'dd' process makes it print I/O
>   statistics to standard error and then resume copying.

And `man 7 signal`:

> ```
>    SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
>    SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
> ```

Combine both statements , you should understand USR1 is **User-defined signal** which is defined by `dd` to provide a way for user to interrupt it and **print I/O statistics** on the fly. It's program specific handler, it doesn't means you can `kill -USR1 other_program_pid` and expect statistics output.

Also you might interest about [this: Why does SIGUSR1 cause process to be terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/why-does-sigusr1-cause-process-to-be-terminated).

Answer (score 6):

This is just a demonstration to illustrate the use of the `USR1` signal with `dd`.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
```

starts `dd` in the background, copying data from `/dev/zero` (which produces zeroes whenever a program reads from it) to `/dev/null` (which discards anything written to it). This provides a harmless instance of `dd` which can be used to experiment with — it doesn't use up any storage, and will keep on running as long as we want it to, which gives the user time to send signals to it.

```
pid=$!
```

stores the process identifier of the last background command (`$!`) in the variable `pid`.

```
kill -USR1 $pid
```

sends the `USR1` signal to the process whose identifier is the value stored in the `pid` variable, the background `dd` in this case. When `dd` receives this signal, it prints out its current progress (the amount of data read and written) and continues copying.

```
sleep 1
```

waits one second.

```
kill $pid
```

sends the `TERM` signal to `dd`, which causes `dd` to exit. (There's no point in leaving the background `dd` running here.)

It would be more instructive to run this instead of the second line above:

```
kill -USR1 $pid; sleep 1; kill -USR1 $pid; kill $pid
```

This would output the progress twice, with one second in between, to show `dd`'s progress; then kill `dd` without waiting.

For actual use, you'd specify appropriate inputs and outputs for the original `dd` command, and probably some other options too, and you wouldn't run the last `kill` — you'd wait for `dd` to finish of its own accord.

To answer your final question, this is how you send `USR1` signals from a shell (or any other signal): you use [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) with the signal you want to send, and the process identifiers (or job identifiers) of the processes you want to send the signal to. Other (non-POSIX) commands you can use are [`pkill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html) and [`killall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html), when you want to find processes by name.

Comment: Last _background_ command.

Answer (score 3):

For most or all shells, `$!` is the process ID (also called PID) of the last process that the shell forked. The `dd` command got forked with the `&`, so that the `pid=$!` right after forking `dd` assigns `dd` process ID to the shell variable `pid`.

A process ID is a number used by Linux or Unix to refer to an address space with some code executing in it.

The `kill` program has an unintuitive name, because its purpose is to send signals (small, asynchronous messages) to processes. There are only a few signals, maybe 128 in total, they have both numbers and names. The "kill" signal is number 9, for example. USR1 is defined as number 10. So the `kill -USR1 $pid` sends signal 10 to the process numbered `$pid`. `dd` sometimes takes a long time to execute, so that's almost certainly the process ID of the `dd` command that got forked earlier, and ran in the background. The `kill $pid` command sends a TERM signal to that same process ID. TERM means "terminate". Well-written programs usually catch TERM, clean up what resources they have allocated and then exit.

I'm not entirely certain why you would run `dd` in the background, send a USR1 signal to it, wait 1 second, and then cause `dd` to deallocate all resources, and exit. The whole code fragment seems to assume that `dd` runs for a long time, which may not be true. I think there are race conditions in this code, and whatever the desired semantics, you may not actually get them.

Comment: I've been searching for a while now trying to find out an alternative util to "kill" whose purpose is to send signal to a process, not kill it.  This is the first time I've read what I've been suspecting - that `kill`'s purpose **is** to send signals, not necessarily to kill a process.  Thanks for stating this - woulda searched longer.  It's very stupid, but so much of programming is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting `dd` command to run in foreground and display current progress status. try running command with `status=progress` flag:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

This will dynamically display the progress.

That's an extension of the GNU implementation of `dd` (added in version 8.24 released in 2015), also available in the `dd` implementation on FreeBSD since 12.0 (2018), but generally not other implementations including on other BSDs.

Comment: Answer does not answer the question.