# How come dd only outputs when I press Ctl+t?

Tags: terminal, osx, logs, dd

This is with OSX.
When I run this in a terminal

```
scottcarlson$ sudo dd if=Downloads/CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1511.iso of=/dev/disk2 2> Desktop/out.txt
```

and then this in another

```
tail -f Desktop/out.txt
```

it only updates the log when I press <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> in the first terminal with the `dd`. Is this because of the nature of `dd`?

I don't know exactly how it writes to devices, but could it be too demanding for the process to take a break and write to the log?

Comment: @jlliagre I believe I'm asking more precisely why it outputs when I press cntl+t.

Comment: Which is precisely explained here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59076/2594

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding that explanation, so is cntl+t a macro for kill -INFO $PID?

Comment: Kind of. It is actually directly sending the SIGINFO signal, just like Ctrl-C is sending the SIGQUIT one. On Linux you would send SIGUSR1 for the same effect, but there is no keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Ahhhh.  That makes sense.  So it's just a built in macro for the SIGINFO signal.   I am not very familiar with that so I will have to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It only updates the log when I press Ctlt in the first terminal with the dd. Is this because of the nature of dd?

Yes. It is in the nature of `dd` to output its current status when it receives a given signal. Under most OSes, this signal is `SIGUSR1`, a standard signal but on OS X, it uses for the same a non standard signal named `SIGINFO`. Moreover, OS X has a `tty` driver setting that allows to send that specific signal with a key combination, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> sends `SIGQUIT` on all OSes.

> I don't know exactly how it writes to devices, but could it be too demanding for the process to take a break and write to the log?

You are precisely asking it to do that with the shortcut. Should you want to have regular automatic updates, nothing forbids you to do a simple shell loop like that one:

```
while kill -INFO $(pgrep dd); do sleep 5; done
```

This assumes `pgrep` is available on OS X. Otherwise, pick the `pid` of your `dd` command and use it as `kill` second argument.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing with <kbd>ctl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> is a summary of the running process information, not `dd`'s output.

`dd` does not output any progress information, unlike what you seem to expect.

If you want to see the actual progress from another terminal window, look at the output file size changing.  In this case you're writing to a raw disk, so patience is probably your best friend here.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I originally did not think dd output anything based on my experience, but a Google search led me to think otherwise.  Can you suggest a good method to see information about the transfer (like percent of transfer completed) for OS X? I have brew installed. In rhel I know how to do it but the same method does not work in OS X.

Comment: Not in your current case where you're writing to a device, not a file.  If it was a file, you could look at the size changing but with a device or partition, there is no way to monitor its progress.  I can imagine many ways that it could be done but not as efficiently and since it's probably very slow already, just let it run until it finishes.

Comment: Well here's to waiting around for 12 hours.. It's a 26gb file haha

Comment: That does seem quite slow.  Are you reading and writing on the same device?  What type of drive is the output device?

Comment: Only writing and it's a 16gb usb 2.0 drive, I'm writing a very large iso.

Comment: It's going at 50kb/s. ... If I remember right

Comment: That **is** slow.

Comment: How is it supposed to fit 26GB of data on a 16GB disk?

Comment: Hahahaha true.. I switched to a larger drive and ignorantly forgot.  It's a 64gb Sandisk.  Still use 2.0.

Comment: If it's really running at 50KB/s, it will take around 6 days to complete.

Comment: Guess I don't remember what the speed was.  It must've been around 500kb/s.  But that's besides the point

Answer (score 0):

On OS-X, if you run `stty -a` you'll see that `^T` is the key combination for `status`

```
% stty -a | grep '\^T'
        min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
```

From `man dd`

```
 If dd receives a SIGINFO (see the status argument for stty(1)) signal,
 the current input and output block counts will be written to the standard
 error output in the same format as the standard completion message.  If
```

The two together mean that while `dd` is running, hitting `^T` will cause a summary display to be written.