# How to monitor the progress of dd command in linux?

Tags: bash, dd

I am copying this `.img` file to my USB flash drive using `dd` command. How can I check its progress ?

Answer (score 3):

If you write to a slow drive, for example a USB drive, you may want to know not only the progress of the command `dd` itself, but also the progress of actual writing to the target device.

You can modify the `dd` command line to make it flush the buffers regularly, for example after writing each mibibyte, and at the same time show the progress, for example

```
  sudo dd if=file.img bs=1M of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=dsync
```

Please check and double-check, that you specify the correct target device. Otherwise you might overwrite valuable data. `dd` does what you tell it to do without any questions.

---

Edit: You can find several other methods in [my answer as well as other answers at this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/how-do-i-know-if-dd-is-still-working/606946#606946).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is by using `progress` in the `status` flag, it will display the seconds elapsed and speed of copying on your terminal.

`sudo dd if=img-file of=/dev/sdc1 status=progress`

Answer (score 1):

`dd` by default uses 512 bytes blocks to copy data which could result in slow data transfers and increased CPU usage. I often prefer to use `cat` or `pv` instead, e.g.

```bsh
pv -petrab img-file > /dev/sdc1
```