# Finding the ID of a process and killing it

Tags: process, grep, kill, ps

When ever I need to kill a background process I do `ps -e | grep <process_name>`

Which prints something like this `1766 ? 00:00:13 conky` , Then I use the process ID to `kill` it like so `kill 1766` .

Is there any way I can simplify this ? Make it quicker ? reduce the amount of typing ?

Comment: This is a special case of [→Q705296](/q/705296 "How to get pid of process with exact name?") "How to get pid of process with exact name?". Albeit it's such a common combination of tasks that `pkill` has been invented for it. 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(TL,DR: `pgrep`, `pkill`)

Many unix variants come with the [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) and its companion `pkill`: [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9nr/index.html), [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) (part of the [standard process utilities](http://procps.sourceforge.net/), may be absent from embedded Linux systems), [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1), [OpenBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1&manpath=OpenBSD+3.5), [NetBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&sektion=1&manpath=NetBSD+1.6), … but [only from MacPorts on OS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225/pgrep-and-pkill-alternatives-on-mac-os-x), [not AIX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-sysadmin1.html), and [only recently in HP-UX](http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/new-tools-pkill-and-pgrep/). The `pgrep` utility shows the process ID of processes matched by name, user and a few other criteria. The argument to `pgrep` is interpreted as a regexp that must match part of the process's executable's name (unless you pass an option to change this). If you call `pkill` instead of `pgrep`, the utility sends a signal instead of displaying the process IDs.

Another similar utility is [pidof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidof). On [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof), it's provided by [SysVinit](http://www.nongnu.org/sysvinit/) or [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) (so you'll often find it on an embedded Linux system that doesn't have `pgrep`); there are also ports on other unix variants. The `pidof` utility has fewer options, it mostly only matches whole executable file names. Its companion utility `killall` sends a signal to the matched programs¹.

¹ 
<sub>Beware that `killall` has a different meaning on Solaris and possibly other unix variants; do not type `killall` as root on Solaris.</sub>

Comment: Wow your answer is very detailed , much more in depth , Thanks. Please edit the question to match the answer if possible.

Comment: @GautamK I don't think the question needs expanding. If you do, feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: Of the answers with the most number of votes Your answer gives more details , so i am accepting it

Answer (score 8):

- `killall ProcessName` (there is a disadvantage with this command in that you don't always know the process name of a program).
- `pidof ProccessName` and `kill the result form pidof`
- `ps xu | grep <process name> | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9` Try this one line and reuse it form the history of your bash, or better create an alias for it .

Comment: The second `pidof` seems a little bit more easier, but still it take 2 steps

Comment: I can search for/create a one line command that do that in one step (with a rough process name) but that would require you to type a long line (which is harder that the two steps above), or you could type it once and reuse it form the history.

Comment: @GautamK i have updated the answer with the single command option.

Comment: @Gautam "more easier". Got it.

Answer (score 6):

While Hanan has some good suggestions, I'll add `pgrep` / `pkill`.  They allow much finer control over which process you find, and regular expressions if you don't know the precise process you'll need to kill.

P.S. Hanan's `pidof` can be fed to `kill` directly with backticks:

```
kill `pidof processname`
```

Comment: `pkill` was exactly what I was looking for , I most of the time know the process name, Mostly its `conky` or `firefox` or `chrome` or something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this -

```
ps -e | awk '$4~/<process name>/{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

**Example:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sleep 100&
[1] 74863
[jaypal:~/Temp] ps -e | awk '$4~/sleep/{print $1}' | xargs kill
[1]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 100
```

**Update:**

Sorry, this obviously does not meet the requirement of less typing so a good way of doing it would be to add a `function` to your `.bashrc`, `.profile` or whatever the startup script. The function can be something like this -

```
killp() {
awk -v pname="$1" '($4==pname){print $1}' <(ps -e) | xargs kill
}
```

Once added, you can simply pass the name of your process:

```
[jaypal:~] sleep 100&
[1] 77212
[jaypal:~] killp sleep
[1]+  Terminated: 15          sleep 100
```